# Show reference label when it is undefined

Tags: bibliographies, citing, warnings

When a reference is undefined, LaTeX shows simply **`[??]`** which doesn't give much information. I would like it to show the label instead. This is useful when more collaborators work on the same preprint and the references are yet to be done.

I'm using neither `biblatex` nor `natbib`. I do use `bibtex` but it is irrelevant for this question.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This: \cite{undef}
should look like: [{\bfseries ?? undef}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's always the `showkeys` package.

Comment: @egreg I know, but that's an overkill here ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The definition of `\cite` calls an internal `\@citex` that checks the citation and adds an `\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}` for undefined citations. Changing it to call the argument to `\cite` instead of the question mark works fine.

```
\makeatletter
% latex.ltx, line 6121:
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries 
     \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@citeb}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

A much cleaner way to redefine `\@citex` is by patching it with [**`xpatch`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@citex}{\bfseries ?}{\bfseries\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@citeb}{}{}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
% latex.ltx, line 6121:
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries 
     \expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@citeb}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\null\vfill\thispagestyle{empty}

This: \cite{undef} should look like: [{\bfseries ?? undef}]

This one \cite{article-minimal} shouldn't.

Ugly citation keys with special chars like \cite{_$^/:&!@*(-=+)} 
also should be printed.

\bibliography{xampl.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image]

<sup>This answer is sponsored by [**`texdef`**](http://ctan.org/pkg/texdef) and (very!) special comments by tohecz and Gonzalo Medina `:)`</sup>

Comment: Works great, unless you have `_` in citation keys. Putting `\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\@citeb` instead of `#2` quite works :)

Comment: @tohecz I felt something was wrong, but couldn't tell what... fixed it!

Answer (score 3):

[`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) provides this functionality by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
\begin{document}
See~\cite{author}.
\end{document}
```